# Migrating from Google+ Sign-in to Google Sign In

Tags: google-plus, openid, google-signin, openid-connect

In 2 days Google shuts down its Google+ service.

I currently fetch user data via this request:  `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect?alt=json&access_token=`

I've looked everywhere, but I cannot seems to find the replacement URL which I should use. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it helps someone else, I found the answer.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect
```

shoud become

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo/
```